# Java Error: please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files

Tags: java, jar, jce

I am working on this Java application which needs to have access to "JCE Unlimited Strength" files and I DO HAVE installed them and it works properly when I build the solution (in Intellij) BUT when I make a `jar` output, for some reason it gives me this annoying error:

```
C:\Users\h\whatever\out\artifacts\Accepter_jar>java -cp Accepter.jar Main
org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdic
tion Policy files
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions.getCipher(CryptoFunctions.java:208)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions.getCipher(CryptoFunctions.java:182)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileDecryptor.hashInput(AgileDecryptor.java:269)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileDecryptor.verifyPassword(AgileDecryptor.java:116)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:282)
        at ExcelJob.loadExcelSheet(ExcelJob.java:22)
        at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have gone through similar issue but with eclipse instead Intellij.
It could be the problem with the jdk(multiple versions) and jre. Go to your **C:\Program Files\Java** directory, add the NEWLY DOWNLOADED JCE jars (depending upon the Java version) inside **security** folder of each of JDK & JRE you have installed.

Comment: Just execute the command: java -version and add the JCE jars to the %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security

Comment: ah thanks man, the problem was the jre library INSIDE the jdk. don't know why they are not using the same jre.

Comment: The classic JDK JRE and the JRE JRE.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows installing the unlimited strength policy files is an annoying task, especially as after every JDK/JRE update you have to do it again.

Therefore I created a Windows batch file that automates the installation for all installed 64 bit Java 8 JREs and JDKs:

```
@Echo Off
FOR /D %%G in ("%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk*.*") DO (Echo Upgrading JDK %%G & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -ir!*.jar -aoa -o"%%G\jre\lib\security" "%~dp0jce_policy-8.zip" > NUL:)
FOR /D %%G in ("%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre*.*") DO (Echo Upgrading JRE %%G & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -ir!*.jar -aoa -o"%%G\lib\security" "%~dp0jce_policy-8.zip" > NUL:)
pause
```

1. [Downloaded from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) the file `jce_policy-8.zip`.
2. Save the script text from above into a text file, e.g. name it `jce_policy-8_install.cmd`. Place it into the same directory as `jce_policy-8.zip`.
3. Now right click the `jce_policy-8_install.cmd` file in the Windows Explorer and select "Run as administrator".

Note the script requires [7zip 64 bit](http://www.7-zip.org/) installed into the default path (`C:\Program Files\7-Zip`).

Answer (score 0):

While running nebeans you will come to know JAVA_HOME path while doing clean and build program ,that time you will come to know where is the java path

IF you are using linux 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
download this jar file and extract it first ,you will find local_policy and US_export.jar file you need to copy those two files into your 
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/security/ copy it here it will ask to overrite say yes. And then re run your netbeans