# Java Opening password protected xslx file throws EncryptedDocumentException

Tags: java, encryption, apache-poi, xlsx, worksheet

I have xlsx file from excel 2013 with password protection.
I have the password—and I was trying to decrypt it.

```
public static Boolean isWorkbookPasswordValid(File file, String xlsWorkGroupPassword) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    Workbook wb;
    try {
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file), xlsWorkGroupPassword);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and running the above code I got this error:

```
org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions.getCipher(CryptoFunctions.java:208)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions.getCipher(CryptoFunctions.java:182)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileDecryptor.hashInput(AgileDecryptor.java:269)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileDecryptor.verifyPassword(AgileDecryptor.java:116)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:206)
    at
```

Reading [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888701/java-error-please-install-jce-unlimited-strength-jurisdiction-policy-files):

so I have downloaded the JCE from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)
and copied it to the java home security directory.

and tried to run again—and I got the same error.

I also tried this code and it gave me the same exception.

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
d.verifyPassword(xlsWorkGroupPassword)
```

adding this propery as well didn't do anything:

```
Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
```

from what I understand excel 2013 encrypt the file by this parameters:

```
keyBits="256",hashAlgorithm="SHA512"
```

and the problem is the `keyBits`. Has anyone had and solved this problem?

Comment: Simply downloading the JCE isn't enough, you have to install it into the right place for it to change anything!

Comment: I have copied it to my java home directory and replaced the existing files . didn't change the error.
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\security

Comment: You have to install the policy files into the JRE you use. The best way is to install it in any JDK and JRE you have installed (32 and 64bit).

Comment: As long as the Exception about "Export Restrictions in place" appears, the JCE is not installed correctly.